# How do I remove this old Sears deadbolt with no visible screw holes?

Tags: deadbolt

I have a very old front door with a moderately old Sears deadbolt which I would like to replace.

[image: Outside]

[image: Side]

[image: Inside]

There are no visible screws or obvious screw holes.

I am able to gently rotate the outer ring on both sides of the door but it does not appear to actually loosen and there are no obvious notches for inserting a screwdriver to pop off a trim plate.

I would prefer to remove it without marring or damaging either the lock or the door as I want to reuse it in a future project. Therefore I've been reluctant to just stick a screwdriver in and start prying.

How do I remove this deadbolt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a wrong answer for you, but here it is...  I found a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Bg1Q6hJRxs) that shows a different lock that uses Allen screws hidden in the bolt bore to hold on the two sides of the lock.  Watch the video if the link still works, but a description is below.

[image: Old lock]

Basically, you need to remove the cover on the end of the door and see if there is space on the side of the bolt to stick an Allen wrench, or at least look in with a flashlight.

You should see a set screw down the bore which can be loosened.  Once the screw on that side is loosened, you should be able to turn the face of the lock to unscrew it from the central mount.  Repeat the step for both sides to fully remove the lock.

Another option that I have seen is that the lock could have a trim cover on the inside that must be pried off to access the screws (the Sears stamped cover could be decorative, hiding screws underneath).  In the examples I saw, it looks like the face plate will get slightly bent or scratched, so I'm not sure I could recommend that unless you know that's the type of lock you have.  Of course, the rim of your faceplate does have a knick in it so...  maybe?

Comment: This is exactly what it is!  I found out from another thread that this is called a "Lori deadbolt".

Comment: @WildcatMatt Awesome!  Thanks for adding the additional picture.  It seems like an elegant design.  Not sure why it fell out of favor.

Comment: I do like that the screws don't show, both from neatness and also a safety angle -- I once cut my finger on a screw with a head that had been badly stripped when it was installed.